# Pointer arithmetic on auto_ptr in C++

Tags: c++

I am reading the implementation of auto_ptr in C++ STL.

I see that commonly needed operations on pointers like -> and * are overloaded so that they retain the same meaning. However, will pointer arithmetic work on auto pointers?

Say I have an array of auto pointers and I want to be able to do something like array + 1 and expect to get the address of the 2nd element of the array. How do I get it?

I don't have any practical application for this requirement, just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you can spend 5 minutes, write a test program and figure this out yourself.

Comment: An array of auto pointers, or an auto pointer to an array?

Comment: The standard only allows pointer arithmetic between pointers that point inside the same array (or one past the end of that array).  So arithmetic on an `auto_ptr` would represent a bug by definition.  See @Bo's answer.

Comment: @Chet: no. The ownership is broken if another *owning reference* to the object exists.

Comment: @Martinho : array of auto-pointers. so conceptually something like :  std::vector<auto_ptr<int>> array[10]; auto_ptr<int> onep; onep=array; onep+1 -> display() ..this is more of a philosophical question as in does overloading arithmetic operations on auto_ptr make any sense..

Comment: Don't do that. `auto_ptr` does not behave well inside containers.

Comment: @Martinho: okkay..yes. Now I also recall having read something on these lines..auto_ptr and containers going bizzare together like if you pass them into a quicksort method etc etc..

Comment: That's one of the reasons it will be deprecated in favor of `unique_ptr` in C++11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An auto_ptr can only point to a single element, because it uses `delete` (and not `delete[]`) to delete its pointer.

So there is no use for pointer arithmetic here.

If you need an array of objects, the usual advice is to use a std::vector instead.

Comment: we can have array of auto-pointers?. so conceptually does something like : std::vector<auto_ptr<int>> array[10]; auto_ptr<int> onep; onep=array; onep+1 -> display() make sense?

Comment: That's an array of vectors of auto_ptr. `auto_ptr` does not work inside containers.

Comment: If you are **really** careful you an have an array of auto_ptrs, but I have never seen one. You can **not** put them in a vector, because the vector might try to make a copy and lose the pointer. If you want a number of `int`s you can just use a `vector<int>` and it will take care of most things, like releasing the memory when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the doccumentation of **[auto_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/)** here.

There is no pointer arithmetic defined for `auto_ptr`.

```
auto_ptr<int>  p1(new int(1));  
*p2 = 5;   // Ok
++p2;       // Error, no pointer arithmetic
```

Answer (score 1):

This has actually nothing to do with pointer arithmetics.

```
// applies as well with soon-to-be-deprecated std::auto_ptr
typedef std::unique_ptr<T> smart_ptr;

smart_ptr array[42];

// access second element
array[1];
// take address of second pointer
&array[1];
// take address of second pointee
array[1].get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Advancing a pointer down an array of objects still works the same. Here's an [example](http://www.ideone.com/RCAMg):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::auto_ptr<int> foo[3];

  foo[0] = std::auto_ptr<int>( new int(1) );
  foo[1] = std::auto_ptr<int>( new int(2) );
  foo[2] = std::auto_ptr<int>( new int(3) );

  std::auto_ptr<int> *p = &foo[0];

  std::cout << **p << std::endl;
  std::cout << **(p + 1) << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Here p is your regular pointer, where I know arithmetic operations + work. I am wondering (and trying) if I can do sth like std::auto_ptr<int> p; and then p+1 etc..and have it make some sense..

Comment: `std::auto_ptr<int> p` means `p` is a pointer to a single integer. So how does `p+1` make sense in that case? Also, what is "sth"?

Comment: sth = something. perhaps not commonly used. yes p+1 will not make sense in this. but I am trying to have an array of auto-pointers and then do arithmetic operations on auto-pointer pointing to base of array. but like someone mentioned that stl defn of auto-pointers do not allow any such arithmetic operators, perhaps because it doesn't make any sense and only complicates things.

Comment: Yes, please don't use stuff like "sth". This is not Twitter and you can type more than 140 characters :-). Look at Bo Persson's answer; an `auto_ptr` cannot be used to hold an array because it will call `delete` instead of `delete[]`. You can either use `unique_ptr` (which has a specialization for array) or a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter for an array.